# Speed up Elasticsearch terms aggregation / SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'd like to know if it's possible to speed up Elasticsearch terms aggregation.

My actual goal is to select multiple distinct fields for some query, for instance, that's a query I'd be using something like this. It potentially could include nested documents later:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "match" : {
      "Company" : "samsung"
    }
  },
  "aggs" : {
    "Products" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "ProductCode"
      }
    },
    "Countries" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "CountryCode"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So I'd find all relevant documents that have samsung as its company and aggregate all of its productCodes and countryCodes (They are integers).

Is there a way to speed such a query? I don't care about the actual `doc_count` brought back, all I need is distinct values. Perhaps there's some sort of hint or a better aggregation to get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a filter query rather than a normal query, it'll improve your initial runtime:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "filtered": {
      "term": {"yourField": "samsung"}
    }
  },
  "aggs" : {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This is because filter queries are pass/fail, rather than having to be scored.

The other things you can do are set your mapping to store these fields as [doc_values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/doc-values.html), which will substantially reduce the memory requirements necessary to perform those aggregations, and to set up [eager loading](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/fielddata-formats.html#_fielddata_loading) on those fields, so that ES will preload that data and have it available for aggregation rather than having to load it on demand, which will improve response times.

We haven't experienced much in the way of downsides with doc_values - they are a clear across-the-board win when you're doing any significant aggregation work. Eager loading will result in slower refreshes, but may be acceptable if you're more sensitive to timely queries than to refresh speed.

Comment: This sounds quite right for me. Our data is refreshed on a weekly basis (+/-) so response rate is much more important than refresh speed. Thanks a lot!